# Search for string in base64 encoded document?

Tags: encoding, base64

I have some data that is stored in a base64 stream.  I need to search for a certain string, let's say "White Rabbit".  Rather than decoding all the records and searching for "White Rabbit" I thought I might be able to *encode* the string and search for that.

I don't know much about base64 and encoding, but I did notice that ANYTHING I encode has an `=` or an `==` at the end of it.  There are no equal signs anywhere else in any encoded string.

So, what does this mean for my search?  Can I just remove the equal signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The = serves as padding. A base64 string will only end with one or two = if they are required to pad the string out to the proper length.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding

As you mentioned, the process would be to encode your search string and then perform a normal search for it after removing any `=` characters..

Comment: I assume that means I can just remove any = that show up on the converted query.  Also, the script is superfluous as the original question did not ask *how* to convert.  I can just use `certutil` or a conversion website.

Comment: Yup, just strip the string. I always give too much. It's nice to have a starting point handed out.